# Feature selection for test data?

Tags: classification, feature-selection

We are applying feature selection for train data.
Assume that we are having 1000 selected features.
The testing data contains more than 1000 features.
It results in prediction error "The number of features at training time in scikit learn".
How can we reduce the number of features in testing data?
Should we apply feature selection for testing data also?

Answer (score 2):

You should have the same features as the training time at the testing time. Normally, you do some feature selection or feature extraction at the training time and do **the same** process in the test time. For example, if by feature selection you find out that it is enough to have a subset of features, you should use **the same subset of features** at the test time. Or if by feature extraction you define a new feature by combining the existing features, you should use the same function for obtaining the new feature at the test time.

I emphasize that you should NOT use a new feature selection/extraction at the test time. You should use the same features that are selected (or extracted) at the training time.

Comment: The same feature selection can be applied. I agree with that. But it will not result in same features that are in training data. How to accomplish this task?

Comment: As mentioned, you should not use the same feature selection **process**. You should use the same **features** that are selected during training time. For example, say during the training you find out that the most relevant features are $f_2, f_3, f_4$. During the test time, you should use the same features $f_2, f_3, f_4$.

Comment: Please refer this link and say. How can i accomplish it?   http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270472/how-to-fix-the-svm-fit-error

Comment: How can i extract the same features in the test set also? Which method can i follow?

Comment: During training you determine which features to keep and during testing you just keep those features and remove other features.

Comment: OK . Thank you very much for your responses. I will try it.

Comment: "You should use the same features that are selected (or extracted) at the training time. " - for an instance if I used 'number of zero crossings' as a feature for my training data(digital signals), I've to compute the 'number of zero crossings' as a feature for the test data also. Am I right?